# Angular: How to detect the reason of NavigationCancel

Tags: angular, navigation, router, guard, azure-ad-msal

Something like that tell me the event `NavigationCancel` occurs, but I would like to know whatever did trigger that:

e.g. AppComponent (excerpt):

```
constructor (
  ....
  private router: Router
)  {
     router.events.subscribe(e => {
       if (e instanceof NavigationCancel) {
         // PLEASE TELL ME, WHO DID CALL ME ? <---
       }
     });
   }
```

Something (a guard, msal,.. etc.) deletes the route every time if I refresh the browser, the last visited `route` is gone. Deep Linking is currently not possible.

A workaround would be: I would have to save the last route in the LocalStorage and force the application to switch to that route. Maybe if I can find the trigger, perhaps I'll find another solution.

**The solution is there (Angular 14+)**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just faced the same problem, and found a way to debug it. Inject `Router` to your page component and subscribe to its events like this:

```js
this.router.events.subscribe(e => {
  // using `instanceof` you can filter the events of interest
  if (e instanceof NavigationCancel) debugger;
})
```

Open DevTools in the browser, and try reproducing the issue. When the debugger is activated, it will be still quite difficult to find the root cause. I had to scroll down the Stack Trace and look through some internal Angular/RxJS code in order to find when the new **navigation event with a different id** is fired.

In my case, turned out that I indirectly called `router.navigate` too soon before the previous navigation was resolved. That's the reason for seeing that error: "Navigation ID 2 is not equal to the current navigation id 3" - Angular Router detected that new navigation (with id=3) has been triggered, and therefore canceled the previous navigation (with id=2), which was almost done. As a result, I had problems with outdated query params.

Introducing an artificial delay before the second navigation solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a `boolean`, you can also return a `UrlTree` from guard with extra parameters. So if you are redirecting to `/home` you would do it like:

```
  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (!this.authService.isLoggedIn) {
      return this.router.createUrlTree(['/home', { message: 'You shall not pass' }]);
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

Then you can read this `message` in the target location with `ActivatedRoute#params`.

Example taken from [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/blog-router-redirects?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcore%2Fauth.guard.ts).

Answer (score 0):

`NavigationCancel` occurs when a `CanLoad` or a `CanActivate` guard prevents the child route from loading. If you want to debug your router events, add `enableTracing: true` to your `RouterModule` [configuration](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule#forroot). Also, `NavigationCancel` has a `reason` [property](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationCancel#reason) which could have useful info.

Comment: There are for about 100 routes and twice more guards. Which of them is active? I've already used tracing and saw the reason, but the reason says nothing except id1 is not id2. I would like the additional info: I was triggered by guard XYZ.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a service that is notified when a guard is failed could work for you.

As you can see it [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/cb339b87f378f2d8e917608566514908e208676e/packages/router/src/router.ts#L589-L594) you cannot make a hook to the router service, so some boilerplate code is required to the guard. If it returns false call your service, that stores guard errors.

Do not forget to remove the errors on navigation start event.

You can issue a feature request for the Angular Team to create such a hook, to be able to get guard errors.

Comment: ok,  thank you, I see, it is currently not possible and requires further modifications in angular source codes,..

Comment: I gave you a possible solution for your problem and further actions that you can move this issue to the Angular Team. I think you could accept my answer.

Comment: yes, thank you, but that is not something new for me, yes that is a solution but not a proper one,.. 